# File.AppendAllText vs StreamWriter

Tags: c#, logging

I want to create a log file to track some operations in my Application.In my scenario within one session I wanna to log at least 50 time per min.currently im using StremWriter to create log file.

```
 public static StreamWriter InitializeStream(string path)
    {
        /*ensuring whether thread safe or not*/
        lock (mylock)
        {
            if (null == _stream)
            {
                var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                _stream = new StreamWriter(fileStream);                    

                return _stream;
            }
            return _stream;
        }
    }

//logging operation
StreamHandler.Log(path)
```

Still im bit confuse to selecting  AppendAllText  or StreamWriter.
Instead of StreamWriter way can i get advantage using AppendAllText Directly?(Performance)

Comment: Why don't you use a logging framework like log4net or NLog?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do not use `AppendAllText()` inside the loop because it uses `StremWriter` internally where stream object will be initialized and disposed on each iteration.