# Locking AppendAllText vs TextWriter

Tags: c#, file, process, locking, textwriter

Regarding the preventing of "already in use" errors i want to ask if the first code snippet could potentialy be dangerous if called multiple times from multiple clients?
Or are both code blocks equaly safe ?

I am asking because the second codesnippet calls a close method which also does a dispose which sounds safer.

```
//FIRST
lock (_myLock)
{
    File.AppendAllText(_filePath, text);
}


//SECOND
lock (_myLock)
{
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(_filePath, true);
    tw.Write(text);
    tw.Close();
}
```

Comment: Why not keep it file handle as long the it is expected to written into? Use locks to control the writes by multiple clients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are both the same. `File.AppendAllText` calls Dispose too.

```
private static void InternalAppendAllText(string path, string contents, Encoding encoding)
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true, encoding))
    {
        writer.Write(contents);
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, there will be the *overhead of opening and closing the file handle*; which may add to cost, if it is being called by multiple clients at multiple times.

Comment: True, but that was not what the OP asked.

Answer (score 1):

Both are equally Safe.

As you have applied the Lock so even if it is called from multiple clients only one thread will be executing at a particular time so it is not dangerous rather first option is more simple

As MSDN says about `AppendAllText` method

`The file handle is guaranteed to be closed by this method`

So in the first piece of code .Net is already doing the extra work your are doing in approach 2

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are doing in latter is already taken care internally when called File.AppendAllText

the same is answered here [File.AppendAllText vs StreamWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380977/file-appendalltext-vs-streamwriter)